# prevent scoped node_modules within node_modules

Tags: node.js, npm

When I use npm install, there are certain node packages that gets installed that contains nested node modules.

Like this:

```
-node_modules
    -packageA
        +js
        -node_modules     <--- needs to be removed/ignored
             +jquery
    -packageA-sub1
        +js
        -node_modules     <--- needs to be removed/ignored
             +jquery
```

Is there a way to specify which packages not to include a nested scoped node_module?

In my case, there are packages that are including jquery (packageA and packageA-sub1, sub2, sub3, sub4, etc), and it's messing up my website because I already include jquery in a few of my plugins. The only way to remedy this is by manually deleting the node_module folder inside the packageA folder.

I tried .npmignore but that doesn't seem to work:

```
packageA/node_modules/
packageA/node_modules
/packageA/node_modules
/packageA/node_modules/
```

I'm using npm 5.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can flatten the `node_modules` hierarchy, when modules share dependencies with the same version, using [`npm dedupe`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/dedupe)

The documentation describes `npm dedupe` as follows:

> Searches the local package tree and attempts to simplify
>   the overall structure by moving dependencies further up the tree,
>   where they can be more effectively shared by multiple dependent
>   packages.

Comment: Not gonna lie.. I was searching for this answer for 6 hours.. then after I posted the question, I found the solution within ten mins.

Comment: @sksallaj NPM would normally do this automatically for you. However, the caveat being "with the same version". Therefore if one module author THINKS he needs jQuery 1.12.0 and another THINKS he needs jQuery 3.0.0 you are still going to end up with two different jQueries. Personally I'd handle this not at the NPM level but at the packer level (webpack, gulp, grunt etc.) and add custom rules to use a specific jQuery

Comment: In my case, I have a plugin that uses many extensions to the same plugin, and each extension has jquery attached, so this perhaps created the problems for me. Dedup removed 24 duplicates of jquery from my packages.

Comment: @sksallaj If the plugin is the primary entry point for your extensions and the plugin already includes `jquery` as a dependency, you could potentially declare `jquery` as a [`peerDependency`](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#peerdependencies) in the extensions.

Comment: Does peerDependencies also handle jquery versioning? For example, what if I have 2.x, and the plugin uses 3.x... or vice versa.. and it works regardless of the version used?

Comment: The `peerDependency` documentation recommends that you ".. make sure your plugin requirement is as broad as possible, and not to lock it down to specific patch versions." You would need to declare a range of possible versions for the `peerDependency` at the extension level, then if it is not compatible with the "host" version (e.g. the version declared in the plugin) then it would fail to install because the peer dependency is not met.